# How to Copy Common properties List<x> to List<y>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

how to copy list to another list

class x and class y  both have several common properties  want to copy common properties to another list ,suppose x to y

Have two list one to copy one list content to another, I use bellow syntax to copy list to list items.

```
List<SomeType2> list1 = new List<SomeType2>();
List<SomeType> list2 = new List<SomeType>();

// This will copy all the items from list 1 to list 2
list1.ForEach(i => list2.Add(i));
```

But My list1 not like same as list2 ,when they have same type of above syntax work perfectly.

My list are not same so I need to use bellow syntax for copy

```
List<Y> y = new List<Y>(x.ConvertAll<Y>(e => { return new Y { Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name }; }));
```

But I don’t want to use static “Id = e.Id, Name = e.Name” ,Need to use this process several time on several list(whose properties are different) so it’s better to me write any common thing which can do that for me.

If have any query please ask,Thanks in advanced.Any type of suggestion will be acceptable

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting list? Should `SomeType` and `SomeType2` inherit from some base type (or eachother)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection

```
static T2 Copy<T1, T2>(T1 from)
{
    T2 to = Activator.CreateInstance<T2>();
    Type toType = typeof(T2);

    foreach (var p in from.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var prop = toType.GetProperty(p.Name);
        if (prop != null)
            prop.SetValue(to, p.GetValue(from,null),null);
    }

    return to;
}
```

---

```
SomeType2 t2 = Copy<SomeType1,SomeType2>(new SomeType1(){/*....*/});
```

Comment: I4V,thanks for reply,will you plz check your static method syntax ,it's show me error.T2 property who are not a member of T1 property,show error message .Thanks for your reply

Comment: @shamim I added the null check.

Comment: I4V Thanks for reply.work on vs2010 Method GetValue() require two parameter,will you please check this,i replace  p.GetValue(from) with p.GetValue(from,null) but it's show me error message ,property mis match.Thanks again for your reply

Comment: @shamim I use .Net 4.5. but if it requires a parameter for `index`, passing a null is fine. I updated the answer.

Comment: Note - this will fail if some objects will have properties with same name but with incompatible types

Comment: @lazyberezovsky and adding `&& p.PropertyType==prop.PropertyType` to `if` would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [AutoMapper](http://stackoverflow.com), it was conceived to do exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map properties with same names, then you can use something like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) (available from NuGet), which will do it automatically for you. Add mapping somewhere on application start:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

Default mapping will provide mapping for properties with same names. So, then simply map lists:

```
List<Source> list1 = new List<Source>();
List<Destination> list2 = Mapper.Map<List<Destination>>(list1);
```

Comment: lazyberezovsky ,Thanks for reply.Mapper,not work for me ,One of my list is anonymous,so it's not working ,show me error message .Will you please show me some guideline how to use Mapper with anonymous list.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.select`

```
List<y> = oldList.select(x=> new y{prop1 = x.prop1}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have common properties, perhaps they should be in an `interface`, or a base class.